# Output Batch file to cmd and Logfile

Tags: windows, batch-file, logging

I am sure this has been asked before but I cant find a definite answer.

I have an interactive batch script that I need to log to a file as well as display to the screen to allow the user to interact with it. Essentially what I would like is for all the text displayed on the screen to be stored in a logfile.

Is it possible to do this with Batch scripts ? I have read that it may only be possible by building up the logfile as the script is run.

I can provide more information if needed,

Thanks!

Comment: "I have an interactive batch script" - where?

Comment: Its a lengthy script that I use for file copies & service restarts. The "interactive" portion is just waiting for yes/no input from the user. My question is about is this even possible to do with batch files rather than specific to my script.

Comment: have a look at `tee`, there are also batch hybrid tees: http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?p=26319&sid=c2ded3bd3f0d1acccd892c6e9f2f8d64#p26319

Comment: @Endoro Thanks for the link. This is almost giving me the result I need so ill look into modifying it to meet my needs. I appreciate the quick answer!